# How to set FreezePanes property of the Windows class?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I heavily rely on "Microsoft Project". Most of my colleagues don't have "Microsoft Project" so I export the project schedule to Excel using VBA.

Sometimes, I encounter this error message

> "unable to set FreezePanes property of the windows class"

Part of the VBA code is as follows.

```vb
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlwindow.Split = True
xlwindow.SplitColumn = AbsoluteColumnPos - 1
xlwindow.SplitRow = 3

xlwindow.FreezePanes = True  ' **
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, but it's always gone at some point.
I can check whether this is specific to the migration from Project to Excel by testing with this VBA code in Microsoft Word.

```vb
Sub Excel_Test()

Dim xlApp As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Activesheet.Range("B3") = 5

With xlApp.ActiveWindow
    .Split = True
    .SplitRow = 4
    .SplitColumn = 11
    .FreezePanes = True
End With

End Sub
```

The same error message

> "unable to set freezepanes property of the windows class"

shows up all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't need this line:

```
xlwindow.Split = True
```

Secondly, you might try to unfreeze first, as I'm not 100% certain that your code is complete, and therefore what might be going on around what you've posted here,  and whether it's possible that a freeze is already operational.  In other words, try:

```
xlwindow.FreezePanes = False

xlwindow.SplitColumn = AbsoluteColumnPos - 1

xlwindow.SplitRow = 3

xlwindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Comment: Thank your for the feedback. But, I always try your advice by adding "FreezePanes = False" both in Project and Word before "FreezePanes = True", and it doesn't work. Then, would it be more of a system error ?

Comment: I'm responsible for a 25,000 line Excel "application" that has a significant interface with Project, and a client who is very finicky with respect to how his windows are arranged, which is why I was drawn to your question, but I've not encountered this issue myself. Does On Error Resume Next (or a GoTo) cope with it in a way that is acceptable from a user perspective?

Comment: I will try it if the error appears next time. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I finally(?) encountered the error. So I added  "Does On Error Resume Next". It worked fine! Though I had to make some manual adjustment to the extracted excel sheet, it was a vanishingly small task. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent :) Do feel free to Accept the answer :)